# Cannot convert value of type 'NSMutableURLRequest' to expected argument type 'SessionManager'

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, nsmutableurlrequest

all.
Nowadays I study, iOS and swift, alamofire by watching Coding for entreprenues. i use swift3 and alamofire4, but they teach it alamofire3 and swift2, so i confused. could you help me what is problem?

there are error like that "Cannot convert value of type 'NSMutableURLRequest' to expected argument type 'SessionManager'"

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        if let Purl = NSURL(string: self.projectUrl){
            var mutableUrlRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: Purl as URL)
            mutableUrlRequest.setValue("JWT \(self.tokenUse)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
            mutableUrlRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
            var getProjects = Alamofire.SessionManager.request(mutableUrlRequest)
                .responseJSON{ response in
                    print(response.request)
                    print(response.response)
                    print(response.data)
                    print(response.result)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alamofire most likely expects native Swift 3 syntax:

```
   if let Purl = URL(string: self.projectUrl) {
        var mutableUrlRequest = URLRequest(url: Purl)
```

`URLRequest` is mutable for free declared as `var`iable.

Comment: Thanks for advise. but there are other issue.

Comment: Cannot convert value of type 'URLRequest' to expected argument type 'SessionManager'

Comment: Isn't it `Alamofire.SessionManager.default.request(...`?

Comment: thanks for advice, it is very helpful for me. have a good weekand!!